# Need to restart phone without hard button

Tags: 8.1, buttons

My switch off hard button is broken. Please I really need an app to restart phone. Is there any app?

My phone is Lumia 625 running Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: it is possible if u had a win 10 on phone

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to remove the battery and put it back in, unless you have an update to install. If you do go to the updates menu in settings and their should be a button to restart and install the updates.